# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache$CachedContextAndSchemas.getContext()Ljavax/xml/bind/JAXBContext

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, pom.xml

I have the following error launching my project with Maven (`clean verify`):

> [ERROR] it.bper.testing.integration.LocalStorageFoldersIT.testLocalStorageFoldersTimeout -- Time elapsed: 9.049 s <<< ERROR!
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache$CachedContextAndSchemas.getContext()Ljavax/xml/bind/JAXBContext;
> at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:356)
> at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceFactoryBean.initializeDataBindings(AbstractServiceFactoryBean.java:87)
> at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromWSDL(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:425)
> at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:527)
> at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:262)
> at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:199)
> at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:103)
> at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientFactoryBean.create(ClientFactoryBean.java:91)
> at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxyFactoryBean.create(ClientProxyFactoryBean.java:158)
> at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create(JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.java:142)
> at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.createPort(ServiceImpl.java:492)
> at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:358)
> at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:349)
> at jakarta.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:139)
> at priv.gbbper.ws.documents_storage.v1.DocumentsStorageV1.getDocumentsStorageSoapV1(DocumentsStorageV1.java:72)
> at it.bper.testing.integration.AbstractIT.(AbstractIT.java:59)
> at it.bper.testing.integration.LocalStorageFoldersIT.(LocalStorageFoldersIT.java:24)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
> at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:250)
> at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:260)
> at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$2.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:309)
> at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
> at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:306)
> at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
> at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
> at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
> at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.pc.Scheduler$1.run(Scheduler.java:345)

This is my pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>it.bper.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>DocumentsStorageWS</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.22.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>documents storage Maven Webapp</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <filenet.cpe.install.path>X:/Program Files/IBM/FileNet/ContentEngine</filenet.cpe.install.path>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <!-- JBoss dependency versions -->
        <version.wildfly.maven.plugin>4.2.1.Final</version.wildfly.maven.plugin>
        <version.wildfly>23.0.0.Final</version.wildfly>

        <!--Use JUnit 5 here - the WildFly bom still brings 4.x -->
        <version.junit4>4.13.2</version.junit4>

        <!-- other plugin versions -->
        <version.compiler.plugin>3.11.0</version.compiler.plugin>
        <version.surefire.plugin>3.0.0</version.surefire.plugin>
        <version.failsafe.plugin>3.2.2</version.failsafe.plugin>
        <version.war.plugin>3.4.0</version.war.plugin>

        <!-- maven-compiler-plugin -->
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Import the CDI API, we use provided scope as the API is included in WildFly -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.wildfly/wildfly-feature-pack -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-feature-pack</artifactId>
            <version>23.0.0.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.26</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Common libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.13.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
            <artifactId>wiremock-standalone</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--
             IBM Filenet libraries
             A runtime servono tutti i JAR, come da documentazione FileNet:
             - Jace.jar
             - stax-api.jar
             - xlxpScanner.jar
             - xlxpScannerUtils.jar
             - log4j.jar (la versione nel FileNet di BPER e' la 1.2.14)
             ma qui riportiamo solo quelli strettamente necessari per compilare
             ed eseguire i test, perche' gli altri JAR sono in WEB-INF/lib
             quindi accessibili dal class loader della web application
          -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.filenet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jace</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>C:/Users/ActionICT-Motti/IdeaProjects/DocumentsStorage_v1/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/Jace.jar
            </systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/javax.activation-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.activation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-xjc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Test libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.soap</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.soap-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            <artifactId>hk2-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            <artifactId>hk2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j2-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--         <dependency>
                 <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
                 <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
                 <version>6.0.1</version>
             </dependency>-->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>
                        --illegal-access=permit
                    </argLine>
                    <parallel>all</parallel>
                    <useUnlimitedThreads>false</useUnlimitedThreads>
                    <threadCount>6</threadCount>
                    <perCoreThreadCount>true</perCoreThreadCount>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>1</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <xadditionalHeaders>true</xadditionalHeaders>
                            <executable>${tool.wsimport}</executable><!-- Piu' veloce nel generare i sorgenti -->
                            <wsdlDirectory>src/main/resources/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
                            <target>3.0</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>external.atlassian.jgitflow</groupId>
                <artifactId>jgitflow-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-m5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <releaseBranchVersionSuffix>RC</releaseBranchVersionSuffix>
                    <noDeploy>true</noDeploy>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.11</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- test unitari-->
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- test integrazione -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare agent integration</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <propertyName>jacocoAgent</propertyName>
                            <classDumpDir>${project.build.directory}/dumpClassDir</classDumpDir>
                            <output>file</output>
                            <append>true</append>
                            <dumpOnExit>true</dumpOnExit>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.0.Final</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!--
                         In produzione c'e' JBoss EAP 6.3 => JBoss AS 7.4.0.Final
                                                      7.4.0 => Wildfly 23
                         ma tale release non e' disponibile nei repo Maven
                         quindi usiamo la versione piu' simile disponibile
                      -->
                    <version>23.0.0.Final</version>
                    <commands>
                        <!-- **These are the commands that aren't going through** -->
                        <command>/subsystem=logging/root-logger=ROOT:write-attribute(name="level", value="DEBUG") </command>
                        <command>/subsystem=logging/console-handler=CONSOLE:write-attribute(name="level", value="DEBUG")</command>
                        <command>/subsystem=logging/file-handler=debug:add(level=DEBUG,autoflush=true,file={"relative-to"=>"jboss.server.log.dir", "path"=>"debug.log"})</command>
                        <command>/subsystem=logging/logger=org.jboss.as:add(level=DEBUG,handlers=[debug])</command>
                        <command>/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/host=default-host/setting=console-access-log:add</command>
                    </commands>
                    <javaOpts>
                        -Xms64m
                        <!--                        -Xmx512m-->
                        <!--                        -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m-->
                        -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
                        -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true
                        -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000
                        -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000
                        -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=100
<!--                        -Djboss.server.config.dir=${project.build.testOutputDirectory}/configuration-->
                        <!--                        ${jacocoAgent}-->
                        <!--                        &lt;!&ndash;per eseguire il debug remoto rimuovere il commento dalla riga sottostante-->
                        <!--                            -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=33333,server=y,suspend=y-->
                    </javaOpts>
                    <port>10090</port>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>start</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <startup-timeout>120</startup-timeout>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>avoid-console-logging</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>execute-commands</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>deploy</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>stop</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>undeploy</goal><!-- Per eseguire "mvn verify" e non solo "mvn clean verify" -->
                            <goal>shutdown</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>loadProperties</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <exportAntProperties>true</exportAntProperties>
                            <target>
                                <exec executable="hostname" outputproperty="computer.hostname"/>
                                <!-- Default "overwrite=false" => non sovrascrive l'eventuale properties gia' presente -->
                                <copy file="src/test/resources/local.properties" tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/${computer.hostname}.properties" />
                                <loadproperties srcFile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/${computer.hostname}.properties" />
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings
                    only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[2.3,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <execute/>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>Jenkins</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                <!--forza l'utilizzo della toolchain JDK 7 per la build -->

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-toolchains-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>toolchain</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <toolchains>
                                <jdk>
                                    <version>1.7</version>
                                </jdk>
                            </toolchains>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <!--Il plugin di JBoss non è toolchain-aware, per cui si deve forzare l'esecuzione di JBoss su JDK7 -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <javaHome>${jdkJenkins}</javaHome>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <properties>
                <jdkJenkins>/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_71</jdkJenkins>
                <!--disabilita il plugin enforcer (perche' non e' toolchain-aware e comunque non serve dal -->
                <!--momento che si specifica esplicitamente il JDK utilizzato tramite JDK toolchain        -->
                <enforcer.skip>true</enforcer.skip>
                <!-- imposta il path di wsimport nel server Jenkins per il maven-jaxws-plugin -->
                <tool.wsimport>${jdkJenkins}/bin/wsimport</tool.wsimport>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

I have tried to add any combination of jaxb related library, from a lot of answers here and in other sites, but still it continues to give this error. Thank you for help.

EDIT

Changing pom according to Laurent answer leads to this

> [ERROR]
> it.bper.testing.integration.GetClassDefinitionIT.testGetClassDefinition
> -- Time elapsed: 5.866 s <<< ERROR! jakarta.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not send Message.   at
> org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.mapException(JaxWsClientProxy.java:183)
> at
> org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:145)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy61.getClassDefinition(Unknown Source)    at
> it.bper.testing.integration.GetClassDefinitionIT.testGetClassDefinition(GetClassDefinitionIT.java:35)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
> org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
> at
> org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
> at
> org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
> at
> org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
> at
> org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
> at
> org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
> at
> org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)    at
> org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
> at
> org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) Caused by:
> org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPException: HTTP response '405:
> Method Not Allowed' when communicating with
> http://localhost:8180/documentsstoragews/DocumentsStorage_v1  at
> org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.doProcessResponseCode(HTTPConduit.java:1643)
> at
> org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1650)
> at
> org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1592)
> at
> org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1389)
> at
> org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
> at
> org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:689)
> at
> org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:63)
> at
> org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
> at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:528)
> at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:439)   at
> org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:354)    at
> org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:312)    at

Comment: You're using `jaxb-core` which uses the `jakarta.xml.bind` namespace, not the old `javax.xml.bind`.

Comment: and then, what I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `pom.xml` file is a bit over-complicated and import dependencies twice.

Here are some suggestions :

- Remove `com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl`: it will import another version of `jaxb-core` under the other groupId that may fail.
- Remove `javax.activation:javax.activation-api`: this is javax-based dependency and is not compatible with cxf 4.x
- Remove `org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-xjc`: this is only needed for XML to Java build, and not needed by your application

Comment: How do you think about adding jakarta activation api?

Comment: Now I have "WebService Could not send Message" error, you know why?

Comment: @Lore : jakarta activation api is taken by transitivity

Comment: Could you share the stacktrace of the error ?

Answer (score 1):

This is related to your used Apache CXF library.
Have you tried to add the cxf-core dependency ?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Haven't solved anything.